# Is there an equivalent to Windows Remote Assistance/iChat screen sharing?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-assistance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Desktop similar to Teamviewer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25609/remote-desktop-similar-to-teamviewer)

I'm used to being able to help my parents through iChat screen sharing on OS X and Remote Assistance on Windows. Is there something that has the same workflow (no setup, works through NATs and firewalls) available for Ubuntu? I'd be very nervous about migrating them to Ubuntu without the ability to help them remotely.

Comment: Also a dupe of: http://askubuntu.com/q/25609/8515

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu has been shipping Empathy for a few releases. It uses the Telepathy framework, which does all the heavy lifting. All you need to do is set up your parents to use gtalk (or some other jabber service) in the chat application, and then when they want to ask you for help, they right click on your name in the name list, and select **Share my desktop**. [My answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11075/how-can-i-enable-the-share-desktop-feature-in-empathy/11076#11076) has more information.

[Here is some information on the feature](http://blog.desmottes.be/post/2009/09/22/Empathy-228:-Easy-Desktop-Sharing)

Answer (score 5):

## [remmina](http://packages.ubuntu.com/remmina) [image: Install remmina]

Remmina is a remote desktop client written in GTK+, aiming to be useful for system administrators and travellers, who need to work with lots of remote computers in front of either large monitors or tiny netbooks. Remmina supports multiple network protocols in an integrated and consistant user interface. Currently RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP and SSH are supported.

Remmina is released in separated source packages:

- `remmina`, the main GTK+ application
- `remmina-plugins`, a set of plugins

Remmina is free and open-source software, released under GNU GPL license.

Comment: Just tried it. Pretty sweet.

Comment: Remmina is a graphical frontend for rdesktop/freerdp, not a remote support utility. So that's not gonna work.

Answer (score 4):

You may try [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). I have personally used it successfully on Ubuntu

Comment: Its non-free software, but it works extremely well.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda. If you have a router with uPNP activated, the share desktop option on the preferences menu will work seamless through the NAT. You only need to check autoconfigure net, the last of the security options.