# What protocols support screen sharing on Empathy?

Tags: empathy, sharing, remote-access, remote-assistance, telepathy

I am trying to follow the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11075/how-can-i-enable-the-share-desktop-feature-in-empathy)  but so far have not found a working protocol so I was wondering if anyone knew of a working protocol that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I just answered that in the [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11075/how-can-i-enable-the-share-desktop-feature-in-empathy/11123#11123)...  ;-)

It currently only works in one of the Jabber/XMPP protocol implementations that exist for Telepathy; the one in the `telepathy-gabble` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

XMPP/Jabber is the main protocol. This means Google Chat, Facebook and normal Jabber accounts should work.

Comment: Have you tested the Facebook & Google Chat account options in Empathy?  It's not entirely clear to me whether they use the Gabble plugin or the libpurple plugin (the one that re-uses Pidgin)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://blog.desmottes.be/post/2009/09/22/Empathy-228%3A-Easy-Desktop-Sharing). Its xmpp protocol.