# Live Support/Chat App for Ubuntu

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, support

Yesterday I was testing the ProvideSupport software from the same providesupport.com site. It had an Ubuntu installer and all but after checking out pricing I was wondering if Ubuntu or in the Linux community there was a similar product that was free that provided at least a way for customers to communicate with the operators or sellers.

For all that do not know, it basically works that you install it on your web site and customers connect to it via a "Live Chat" system that you then connect to the operators or people that will answer your call. Its pretty neat but a free version would be nicer and even more if in the debian/ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of them. Empathy is installed by default and supports loads of protocols, including XMPP, which Google and Facebook also uses. So you don't have to install that. You do need a server, however, and there are several of those as well, like ejabberd. (Jabber and XMPP) are two names for the same thing, although XMPP is the official one now). There are many browser clients available, written in HTML/CSS/JavaScript, Flash and Java.

I suppose you'd simply configure the XMPP server to pick an available support person on a round robin fashion and forward the chat to them.

References:

- [How can I enable the "Share Desktop" feature in Empathy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11075/how-can-i-enable-the-share-desktop-feature-in-empathy)

Comment: You know I just noticed I was dumb to not look for xmpp lol. I mean obvious ^^. Thank you Jo-Erlend.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your information here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuLiveChatSupport.
I think it will help somewhat with your live account