# Empathy Audio Call, Video Call, Desktop Sharing and File Sending not working

Tags: 12.04, empathy, remote-desktop

When trying to make a Video or Audio Call from a Gmail account to another Gmail account it throws a window error with the following output: **There was an error starting the call**

I have the Gmail plugin to talk and checked any Empathy extensions needed for this. The problem happens only on 11.10. in 11.04 it works correctly.

The problem has expanded to Desktop Sharing and Sending files. Both of which do not work either. I think this is all related to a common problem.

UPDATE - Desktop Sharing can be solved by activating `vino-preferences` and configuring in the host. After that tell the Empathy host to "Share Desktop". It should work. File Sharing has been solved in one of the updates that came several days ago. The issue still exists for Audio and Video.

UPDATE 2 - Since around June 2012 in 12.04 the option about activating vino-preference to have Desktop Sharing is not working.

Comment: I tried to install the last version of telepathy/empathy via the ppa repository. But still I have the same problem mentioned by Luis. This bug seem to be present also between empathy-empathy, and empathy-gtalk users. Also I cannot receive calls from other empathy users. It is a bit depressing bug, especially for the ufficial chat-program of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer that everything works in 12.10 or 12.04 updated but the part about remote connection is now handled by Remmina Remote Desktop Client since trying to install everything as mentioned in [How can I enable the "Share Desktop" feature in Empathy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11075/how-can-i-enable-the-share-desktop-feature-in-empathy?lq=1) still does not work. So if you are one of the users that this does not work when:

- Both users are using Empathy
- Both have `vinagre` installed
- Both are using the same ubuntu version (just in case)
- Both are using a gmail account (jabber)

Then the only way would be to either use Google Hangout or Remmina.

Answer (score 0):

As I also wrote at [How can I enable the "Share Desktop" feature in Empathy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11075/how-can-i-enable-the-share-desktop-feature-in-empathy/397454#397454)

It does work for me if:

- The sharing person once has to adjust the settings in "vino-preferences" for others to be allowed to view and control their screen.
- And the viewing person has to have "vinagre" running.

Sharing from linuxmint 13 (ubuntu 12.04), viewing from linuxmint 15 (ubuntu 13.04).