# Remote Desktop similar to Teamviewer?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm looking for an application similar to teamviewer to install on ubuntu 10.10.
I know that the teamviewer's staff has released a version for ubuntu, but I'd like to use something completely open.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Please tell us what software you chose and why, it'd be greatly appreciated for others looking for alternatives.

Comment: At moment I didn't find any that can replace teamviever.I hope that someone creates a program like that just for Ubuntu

Comment: Teamviewer is a tool I'd be willing to pay for if I did tech support for money.

Comment: I stumped upon this as I am looking exactly same answer. Were you able to figure out some good alternatives? what is an 'idem' which you mentioned as lacking in Remmina?

Answer (score 6):

This page is a comparison of remote desktop software available for various platforms.

[Comparison of remote desktop software](http://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Features)

See Features column -> **NAT Passthrough**: the ability to connect to the server behind a NAT without configuring the router's port forwarding rules. It gives an advantage when you can not configure router (for example it is on Internet service provider's side), but is a serious security risk (unless the traffic is end-to-end encrypted), because all the traffic should pass through some proxy server which in most cases is owned by remote access application's writers.

Comment: I saw the characteristics of every one of those, but I don't thing that there is an alternative that replaces teamviewer...at moment!!

Comment: The TeamViewer feature that OP is looking for is not just NAT Passthrough but UDP hole punching (ie, using a third-party server to initiate the connection, bypassing the firewalls).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly we should make something clear:

There is:

1. **Remote Desktop** -- where you log in to a remote machine , most common to a server and work on it as you were there. In this case you would not see what other logged on users are doing on the same machine (Server) you would see your login and your desktop only.

For this purpose I have been using:

**Remote Desktop Connection** (from Windows),

**Remmina** with RDP protocol (from ubuntu)

2. **Remote Support** -- When you connect to someone else's PC and control their logon session as you were them. If you move your mouse it moves their cursor, and same with keyboard.

For this purpose I have been using:

**TeamViewer** (from Windows, ubuntu, Fedora)-(bypasses Firewall very well),

**SimpleHelp** (from Windows)-(ports 9005? should not be blocked outbound) and recently

**ConnectWise** (formerly named ScreenConnect) (from Windows, ubuntu)-(ports 8040-8041 should not be blocked outbound),

you *might* be able to use **Remmina** with the VNC protocoll but I am totally unfamiliar with VNC.

We use ScreenConnect at the moment for remote support to troubleshoot and fix customers PCs, TeamViewer is a bit better overall but it is extremly expensive, ScreenConnect is on the same level of quality (tested more on Windows), but much more affordable. If there would have been an opensource program which could do Remote Support we would use it, but we haven't find anything good so far.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/?platform=linux&license=opensource).

One app named Remote desktop viewer is already(Applications -> Internet) installed in ubuntu.

Comment: I know about that, the the problem is that I've to connect me to a remote PC back a firewall. The administrator doesn't want to open a port or make a nat on firewall toward the PC. The only solution I've found is teamviewer that works with a ID. I'd like to use something like it but open!

Comment: so you should see the link for the alternatives.

Comment: There is no open alternative that bypasses firewalls as easy as Teamviewer on that link.

Comment: After I have made a lot of searches, I've decided to use teamviewer for my reason!!!there aren't alternatives like it