# How to config ddclient and make the pc in a NAT availabe to a client in internet?

Tags: networking

How to config the ddclient to make my pc which is in NAT accessible from a pc  in the internet?

Answer (score 2):

[Ddclient](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ddclient/) can be configured by running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ddclient
```

in a terminal. This will create a `/etc/ddclient.conf` file that can be further edited to meet your needs, e.g.for the service you use for IP detection.

To make your lokal client accessible remotely you need to forward ports for the given remote services to your local client. You may also need to configure PAT or NPAT if many clients share a public IP.

If you don't have access to your router you can try to setup a SSH tunnel on existing open ports (see [here](https://serverfault.com/q/33283) and [there](https://serverfault.com/q/244396)). To have remote desktop access you may also consider [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/q/25609).

Comment: yes, many pc share a same IP and is it possible to config pat on my pc?

Comment: This needs to be done on the router.

Comment: really sad.