# Remote desktop from ubuntu to  windows?

Tags: windows, vnc, remote, rdp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Desktop similar to Teamviewer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25609/remote-desktop-similar-to-teamviewer)

I want alternate to Dameware which will be free. As i want to give remote support from Linux desktop to windows desktop. Avoiding VNC we need install VNC server on all windows desktop. Can't use RDP because want same session.

Want something in which can install software over air.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried TeamViewer ? It's free as long as your not using it commercially. Its great to remote in to Windows, Mac , and Linux Systems.  *http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx*

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is also [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) for Widows and Mac. You can install the [LogMeIn Free](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/) client on the Windows/Mac machine. After that, add the same Windows/Mac machine to your free logmein.com account. Then, you can access the Windows machine remotely via any Web Browser. (Note: You need to have Flash plug-in installed on your Linux machine in order to access the remote machine).

The [LogMeIn Free](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/) client has certain limitations as to what all you can do. These limitations can be overcome using the [LogMeIn Pro](https://secure.logmein.com/products/pro/) client. Read: Paid.

There are many more LogMeIn products for a wide range of situations. You can check them out yourself: https://secure.logmein.com/products/default.aspx. There is also one product ([LogMeIn Rescue](https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/HelpDesk/Home.aspx)) in which no software is required to be installed on the remote machine, but it is a paid version.

Comment: no team viewer pr logmein

Answer (score 0):

You can use rdesktop package in linux machine to take remote session of windows machine. No need to install anything in remote windows machine. I had tried this few times in past and it had worked for me. I was able to get rdesktop package on internet.
Good Luck.

Comment: Want the same session.