# How to install and configure X11RDP?

Tags: x11rdp

I surf the web without finding a good tutorial how to install and configure X11RDP since XRDP is making some problems and i found that X11RDP solved this issue.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the post marked as "the answer" is basically my Scarygliders Xrdp-o-Matic script which the person concerned has merely cloned from an older version and made some changes of their own. Since that happened I have made lots of changes to the original and it's now up to v3 as at time of writing this answer, with many enhancements - including the creation of debian packages. It works on Debian-based distros including Ubuntu. Whilst I'm glad people are using my tools, and they've been released with a very open source license (ISC) , if you're going to use the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you visit the [scarygliders](http://scarygliders.net/)?!

Try it, it's a very nice website

---

OK, Finally I am ready to provide you my script

check this [link](https://github.com/makinux-git/x11rdp-makinux) on gitHub and download the folder

I have uploaded all needed packages for installing x11rdp and xrdp together

I have pre-answered all dialogs and choose Ubuntu-2D for Interface and for All Users

What You have to do is to only execute the setup.sh script via `sudo sh setup.sh`

*Uploaded on GitHub, and changed the link

Comment: I visited before but its just didn't work for me

Comment: i am working on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Your answer becomes worthless if that link becomes invalid.  Please upload this - for example github or launchpad - so that your answer remains relevant.

Answer (score 0):

scarygliders is by far the best tool to build the very latest x11rdp and auto install it for you.