# How to access and use another Ubuntu over LAN?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remote-x-session, x11rdp

I'd like to have seamless control over my computer from my laptop within my home LAN. After seeing this post, it would seem that seamless (no lagginess at all, which VNC introduces) control is possible - but I'm not sure which technologies would work.

I've tried VNC, even with compression on, but there is still a bit of a delay in the frames .

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possibilities:

1. VNC
2. VNC + SSH Tunnelling
3. [NX Server](http://primozverdnik.com/2012/05/nomachine-nx-desktop-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-no-menus/)
4. [free edition FreeNX](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2012/05/how-to-install-freenx-on-ubuntu-1204.html)
5. NeatX
6. [X2Go](http://jsmcomputers.biz/wp/?p=320)
7. X11 Forwarding over SSH
8. [X11RDP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190838/how-to-install-x11rdp-on-ubuntu-12-04)
9. xrdp
10. [teamviewer](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-team-viewer-version-7-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin.html)

etc......and many others

Comment: Are any of these "seamless" though? I'm getting my inspiration from http://unigine.com/devlog/2012/09/07/101 and getting the idea that it's possible. I already tried VNC, is it not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I researched a lot and have answered that question with x11rdp. check [my post on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/190838/91632)