# problem installing make command, x11rdp and libxcb1-dev package

Tags: dpkg, x11rdp

I installed x11rdp using the tip here [How to install and configure X11RDP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190838/x11rdp-best-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-12-04), its a script that download, build, install and configure x11rdp, I ran once the `sudo bash setup.sh`, it didn't work because I didn't have the command `make` so I installed it, the make command ran without trouble except by the package `libxcb1-dev`, who seems broken, I tried ran `apt-get -f install`, it didn't work again, I tried update by the update manager, same problem again, I tried use synaptic and didn't work again, any idea to solve that problem or any idea if is something that I have done wrong or that script has done wrong or if its a problem in the package?? 
by the way, even with the broken package I could install x11rdp with the script and I am using without trouble.

here the LOG:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxcb1-dev: Depends: libxcb1 (= 1.8.1-1) but 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
Depends: libxau-dev (>= 1:1.0.0-1) but 1:1.0.6-4 is installed
Depends: libxdmcp-dev (>= 1:1.0.0-1) but 1:1.1.0-4 is installed
 ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
and log into the `apt-get -f install`
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  libxcb1-dev
  libx11-dev
  libxfixes-dev
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

 A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb1-dev:
  libxcb1-dev depends on libxcb1 (= 1.8.1-1); however:
   Version of libxcb1 on system is 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1.
 dpkg: error processing libxcb1-dev (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libx11-dev:
  libx11-dev depends on libxcb1-dev; however:
   Package libxcb1-dev is not configured yet.
 dpkg: error processing libx11-dev (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxfixes-dev:
  libxfixes-dev depends on libx11-dev; however:
   Package libx11-dev is not configured yet.
 dpkg: error processing libxfixes-dev (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  libxcb1-dev
  libx11-dev
  libxfixes-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Install [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) if you have not done so already. This provides various packages useful for building software in Ubuntu. It can be installed in the Software Center or by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: I don't think this will help. Installing `build-essential` will just fail when it tries to install `make` (one of its dependencies). It's worth a try, though.