# remote assistance application

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-assistance

I goggled around a lot but I didn't find a proper answer to my question, so I'm going to ask it here.

I convinced my parents to switch to Xubuntu and I would like to offer them remote assistance whenever they need. I also have an Xubuntu box. Which are the client / server applications that I need to install to perform remote assistance?

thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/q/25609/236. Maybe you find answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options available to you.  Without needing to punch holes in their firewall, I'd say, install Google Chrome, and use the remote desktop app that runs in the browser.  After that, Teamviewer works well too.

There are lots of remote desktop software in the repos, but you'd need to use port forwarding on their router.

bertman

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will give a try to Chrome. However, I'm not a fan of Chrome/Chromium and I would like to use some "designed-for-ubuntu" application as well

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer on premise solution (soho-server or openwrt router) you can use Ubuntu's (or any other Linux) built-in tools (`ssh`+`x11vnc`+`tigervnc`). Works through any combination of NATs. The repository below contains a script for a user-friendly connection of all these tools:

https://github.com/skosachiov/linux-remote-assistance

Сonvenient to use in a corporate environment, as Ansible is used for deployment.