# Free remote support applications?

Tags: remote-access, software-recommendation, remote-assistance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent to Windows Remote Assistance/iChat screen sharing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370/is-there-an-equivalent-to-windows-remote-assistance-ichat-screen-sharing)

I'm using TeamViewer right now from my Ubuntu system to provide remote support for other Linux and Windows systems. I also have a paid logmein account, but I can't use that in Linux. Are there any other good free remote support utilities like TeamViewer for Ubuntu?